# server out of memory - mysql processes?

Tags: linux, mysql, php, lamp

I have inherited a system build in PHP (LAMP) and it keeps going offline due to running out of memory every week or so. There's 4gb of RAM available. I've asked my hosting provider twice to look in to the issue but there doesn't seem to be any logs, despite having log rotation turned on in plesk.

When running the mysql command SHOW PROCESSLIST I currently have 4826 processes (and forever counting) - and Google Analytics says there are currently about 13 people on the site, so the processes seem rather excessive.

I have just added this to the mysql/my.conf to help fine tune things

[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=180
wait_timeout=180

But could this be the problem? I know it's hard to pin-point, I have tried setting up error logs via plesk and php error logging but apparently nothing seems to output at the time of going out of memory - I run out and have to restart and this happens quite often at different times of day every week or so.

Any ideas for where to look would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Tim

Comment: It sounds like your app is holding database connections open and mysql isn't killing them off. I'd look at your application too.

Comment: Sound like OOM is switched off. Switch it on - so you can at least see which process is being killed by OOM. Try to redirect your system-log to a remote-server, too.

Answer (score 0):

When you say there are no logs, do you mean at all (in which case - check to make sure you have some form of syslog running!), or only when you experience the issues?

Also take a look at top to see what's using up most memory (i.e. check if it really is mysqld or not).